# PHP input field (with username), check if username is in active directory

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, active-directory

I have a form with the following input of a username:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="affuser">Affected User: <font color="red">*</font></label>
<div class="col-sm-10"> 
  <input type="affuser" class="form-control" name="affuser" id="affuser" placeholder="Username" value="" required="required">
</div>
```

I would now like to check if this user is also in an active directory of my company. So when a username is written in the input field and the cursor gets out of the field (for example) then there should be a check if this user is in the AD or not. If it is then the borders should become green, if not the borders of the input field should become red. And if there is a "wrong" input the field should also not be able to be submitted.

How can I solve this as good as possible?

Comment: I don't see any form, please include all the relevant code.

Comment: You should probably do a bit of php coding to your mysql database, and an ajax request. You have not tried anything except some html..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okaay, baby steps.

First, you need to check for the user in the AD, you'll need to perform an ajax call to your **back-end** when the cursor gets out of the field using an **javascript event**, when you *complete* your ajax call, you'll check for the result returned by the back-end and change your field border using the javascript **style** function, then, you will add an **event** to your form to check for all fields, before send it.

As you didn't try to do this, I just gave you the highlighted subjects that you need search for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but you cannot solve that only with PHP. PHP runs on the server and because you probably want to embed that snippet into a webpage, you cannot run PHP directly in the page. You would have to use JavaScript with AJAX to ask a PHP-Site on the Server to check whether the user exists or not.

That means that you would need a code on the webpage, that waits for the input to lose focus. That is easily possible with JQuery's [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

After that you would need to call the server. Easily possible with JQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

You need to create a new PHP document checking whether the user is in the active directory or not, that is callable by the AJAX-Call. To check that you could use [LDAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php).

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to call an API provided by Active Directory. Best thing would be to use a ready to use PHP SDK for this to call it via PHP.

You can checkout adLDAP (http://adldap.sourceforge.net/) for instance.

(The latest stable version is available here : https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP/tree/v4.0.4)

Also make sure LDAP is even enabled/installed in PHP. Check out this article: http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php

Steps:

- Send the username (via html form or via Ajax as suggested) to your webserver
- pass the username via the respective SDK function to the LDAP API
- check the result returned by the API in PHP
- respond to the browser dependant on what result the API check returned